# How do I navigate to a CD drive?

Tags: cd-command, disk, elementary-os

I'm trying to install Virtualbox Guest Additions in Elementary OS.  `cd` doesn't seem to work with `cd VBOXADDITIONS_4.2.6_82870`.

**Update:** I did what @ivica recommended, and here's what I'm getting:

[image]

I see that I'm supposed to run either `autorun.sh` or `runasrood.sh` or `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`, but what program am I supposed to run it with?

Answer (score 2):

What is your host OS? When you run ElementaryOS guest, click Device menu, then Install guest additions, which should download the ISO (maybe it already did). Either way, that ISO gets mounted to `/media` or `/mnt`.

Comment: Windows 8.1 is my host- I did do that. Do I need to click "Install guest additions" before booting in, or something?

Comment: No, click it after ElemOS fully boots and it should get mounted like a new drive, with `run.sh` (something like that) script on the drive that installs it.

Answer (score 0):

Since from the screenshot it would appear that you're able to see the CDROM device I'd drop to a terminal and run this command to find out the path that the CDROM device is being mounted at.

As others have said most of the distros are using `/media` as some form of the mount point for removable media. I'm on Fedora 19 but this method should work the same for you. Using this command in a terminal will show you the device & path that's being used to mount the removable media:

```
$ mount | grep media
```

#### Example

```
$ mount | grep media
/dev/sr0 on /run/media/saml/Fedora 19 x86_64 type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500,uhelper=udisks2)
```

From the above we can identify that the device being mounted is `/dev/sr0` and the directory where this device is being mounted is `/run/media/saml/Fedora 19 x86_64`.

So to change to the directory:

```
$ cd /run/media/saml/Fedora 19 x86_64
```